# check if elements in array are consecutive --- javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array as

```
arr = [1,2,3,4,6,7,8,9]
```

Now I want to check if the values in the array are consecutive.

Being more specific, I want this

First Check gives first and second element are consecutive and the next element is not consecutive then the algo must return the first element from where the consecutive number started

Like

```
First Check will give 1
Second Check will give 6
and so on...
```

Please help
Thanks in advance

Comment: Is this an assignment? It seems like it. If so, show what you've tried so far and where you are stuck. If not, could you explain the context that requires you to do this?

Comment: I want an algo which will return me the values as I described in the end

Comment: @Rohit - What about a standalone number? for example should  `[1,2,3,4,6,8,9]` return `1, 6, 8`, or just `1, 8`?

Comment: have you tried a simple loop?

Comment: if the array is [1,2,3,4,6,8,9] then it should return 1,6,8 i.e it should return the number from where we started getting the consecutive number

Comment: Do you want it to literally return `1,6,8` in an array or string, or do you want to run it multiple times getting the next number on each run?

Comment: I want to run it multiple times getting the next number on each run

Comment: This is farily basic stuff. Give it a try first.

Comment: @James I wasn't able to solve this "FAIRLY BASIC STUFF". PLease guide me

Comment: @Rohit. So, show us where you got to. You've obviously got some code that doesn't work - show us that and we can work from there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One sidenote is that you want to call it multiple times, so each call should know which array it's working on and what the previous `offset` in that array was. One thing you can do is to extend the native `Array` object. **[[Demo](http://jsbin.com/awada5/3/edit)]**

```
Array.prototype.nextCons = (function () {
  var offset = 0; // remember the last offset
  return function () {
    var start = offset, len = this.length;
    for (var i = start + 1; i < len; i++) {
      if (this[i] !== this[i-1] + 1) {
        break;
      }
    }
    offset = i;
    return this[start];
  };
})();
```

**Usage**

```
var arr =  [1,2,3,4,6,8,9];
arr.nextCons(); // 1
arr.nextCons(); // 6
arr.nextCons();​ // 8
```

Comment: Why not just hand in the last index returned as the place to start this one at?

Comment: I suppose so. In your case,I think it returns increasing values greater than the length of the array if called more times than there are non-consequitive elements, and there's no way of resetting it to the beginning of the array...

Comment: @Paul - It depends on what the OP expects, but the code is fairly simple to modify.

Comment: How would you modify it to reset it? (just curious)

Comment: `... return function (reset) { if (reset) offset = 0; ... }` then both `arr.nextCons(true);​` and `arr.nextCons("reset");​` will do.

Answer (score 5):

```
/**
 * Given an array of number, group algebraic sequences with d=1
 * [1,2,5,4,8,11,14,13,12] => [[1,2],[4,5],[8],[11,12,13,14]]
 */
import {reduce, last} from 'lodash/fp';

export const groupSequences = (array) => (
  reduce((result, value, index, collection) => {
    if (value - collection[index - 1] === 1) {
      const group = last(result);
      group.push(value);
    } else {
      result.push([value]);
    }
    return result;
  }, [])(array)
);
```

Answer (score 4):

```
 /**
 * Given an array of number, group algebraic sequences with d=1
 * [1,2,3,4,5,6] => true
 * [1,2,4,5,6] => false
 */
 const differenceAry = arr.slice(1).map(function(n, i) { return n - arr[i]; })
 const isDifference= differenceAry.every(value => value == 1)
 console.log(isDifference);
```

Answer (score 2):

Check if all numbers in array are consecutives:

**Updated March 2022**

```
 const allConsecutives = (arr) =>{ 
    if(arr.some(n=> typeof n !== "number" || Number.isNaN(n))) return false;
     return arr.every((num, i)=>  arr[i+1]-num === 1 || arr[i+1] === undefined)
  }
```

Comment: this returns true when arr = [8,0] also [0,0] so doesn't work perfectly.

Comment: You're right @CarlSala I just corrected it, Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

pseudo code:

```
int count = 0 
for i = 0 to array.length - 2 
    if  {array[i + 1] - array[i] = 1 then 
        count+=1 
         return i
    else count=0}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const array1 = [1,2,3];
const sum = array1.reduce((accumulator, currentValue) =>{
  return accumulator + currentValue;
});
const max = Math.max(...array1);
  maximum = max
  if(sum == maximum * (maximum+1) /2) {
       console.log(true);
  } else {
       console.log(false);
  }
```